# Is there a logic to the Megaman X password screen?

Tags: mega-man-x

Playing Megaman X, at the end of every stage i'm given a Password Screen.

[image]

That password is like a shortcut to get back where you were in the game.

But is there a logic to that screen? Could I create a password to get a gamefile that is exactly what I want?

Comment: Fun semi-unrelated fact, if you reset your console/emulator and go in password. It will have saved your last password and you can continue your progress this way without entering it manually.

Learned this by accident after over a decade of playing regularly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a nice write up about how it works located on [GameFAQs](https://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/562670-mega-man-x/faqs/52749) . It seems to cover everything that you are asking here is an excerpt:

> To explain the mechanics of the password system, it's necessary to
>   note the limitations of it.  The system is not designed to record your
>   exact position in terms of lives, health, or amount of progress made
>   through any one of the levels.  It doesn't even record progress made
>   into the stages beyond the initial eight bosses.  Instead, the
>   passwords keep track of only 24 binary variables.
>
> These 24 variables have only two possible values, true or false.  What
>   this means is that all they keep track of is whether you HAVE
>   accomplished a certain feat, or HAVE NOT accomplished that feat.
>   There's one for each of the eight bosses, to keep track of whether
>   you've defeated each of them or not, another eight for each of the
>   heart tanks, to determine if you've collected them or not, four more
>   for the sub-tanks, and another four for the armor upgrades you can
>   gather (boots, helmet, mega buster, and body armor).

Also from the same link above someone apparently made a Mega Man X password generator which can be found [here](http://www.mmhp.net/Passwords/MMX1/).

Comment: I've decoded this back in high school.  You can generate a password that gives you all the upgrades without any subtank or weapons.